# Java Webservices Load testing using JMeter

Tags: java, web-services, jmeter

I am trying to test our Corebank system developed in Java-Wicket framework.
MY requirement is to call direct server URLs and perform operations. It is a secured application, so an authentication is needed first (Basic authentication - Username and password).
I am getting an error for authorization header in the start.
After login I need to create saving accounts and fetching info related to saving accounts like account balance and all.

So I wanted to know that is JMeter testing feasible for this webservice testing .
Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

JMeter is an EXCELLENT tool to test a webservice - both funational & performance testing - which i have done in my project. Both SOAP & REST.

Actually it is much better than SoapUI because with JMeter you can easily read the data from CSV and Parameterize it. SoapUI free version does not provide the option.

To pass authentication

Enable this in jmeter.properties

```
httpclient.parameters.file=httpclient.parameters
```

Enable this in httpclient.parameters

```
http.authentication.preemptive$Boolean=true
```